# Checking if a field contains information

Tags: templating, conditional, entry-type

I have read docs on Craft CMS site and Googled some related articles but can't seem to get my head around checking for conditions for a field.

For example, if I have a 'Fruit' field drop-down:
Apple
Banana
Orange

Should I add a 4th value with 'null'? So in my template, I want to display the field if it is Apple, Banana or Orange but not if null.

I get confused when to to use '|length'  or 'is empty' or 'is not' conditionals.

In another example, I tried to setup a drop-down for a field called 'Rating'
The values were 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
I couldn't get the conditional to work, so I thought to make the field a number type. And then I tried a conditional 'rating > 0' but also didn't succeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a Dropdown field with the option to *not* select a value (or to clear out the current selection), you can just add an option (typically the first) with an empty `value` column. If the empty value/option is selected, the following conditional will evaluate to `false`, and if any other, non-empty value is selected it will evaluate to `true`:

```
{% if entry.dropdownFieldHandle %}
    I have a value: {{ entry.dropdownFieldHandle }}
{% else %}
    I have no value in the dropdown
{% endif %}
```

Note that for Dropdown fields its also possible to leave the `label` column empty, or to use something like "Pick a value..." as a placeholder.

If you use `null` instead of an empty value, the above conditional will always evaluate to `true`, because Twig will treat the value `null` as a string (i.e. `"null"`), not an actual `NULL` value.

As for the `|length` filter, since your question brings it up – the only thing `|length` does is to return the *length* of whatever variable its suffixed to. For an iterable object (like an array or a relational field like Assets or Entries) the length will be the amount of elements in that object (for instance, the number of Assets selected in an Assets field); for strings and numbers it will be the number of characters (meaning `"foo"|length` and `123|length` will both return `3`).

The reason `|length` is often used in conditionals, is that `0` is considered a "falsey" value, and any length larger than `0` is considered a "truthy" value. In other words, a conditional like `{% if ""|length %}` will be evaluated to `false`, because `""` is an empty string and hence will return `0` characters, while a conditional like `{% if "foo"|length %}` will evaluate to `true` because the `length` filter will return `3` characters and `3` is a "truthy" value.

That being said, the reason why the `|length` filter isn't neccessary in the above example conditional is simply because Twig will automatically evaluate conditionals testing empty strings to `false`. So while `{% if entry.dropdownFieldHandle|length %}` would also work (i.e. evaluate to `false` for empty values), it isn't actually neccessary.

Finally, `is not` (or simply `not`) is simply Twig-speak for the `!=` operator, i.e. `is not equal to`. So if you wanted to reverse the conditional above, here's how that would look:

```
{% if not entry.dropdownFieldHandle %}
    I have no value in the dropdown
{% else %}
    I have a value: {{ entry.dropdownFieldHandle }}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: I changed the first value to blank (no data) and tried:

{% if entry.GamesGraphicsMode %}Graphics Mode: {{ entry.GamesGraphicsMode }}{% endif %}

But the result is that 'Graphics Mode:' is shown regardless of whether I have the drop-down selected to the first option (blank) or an option with data.

Comment: Is the option value really empty, or did you accidentally make it a blank space or something like that? Also, note that Dropdown fields are not dynamic – i.e. if you change the `GamesGraphicsMode` field's options (e.g. by changing an option value from `"null"` to an empty value), any existing values for your entries won't update; you'll need to resave existing entries. You can always try to `{{ dump(entry. GamesGraphicsMode) }}` and see what it contains, because I guarantee that it isn't empty :)  (the `dump` function requires [`devMode`](https://craftcms.com/support/dev-mode) to be on)

Comment: I got it to work. I set the first Label to "Select" and option to "select", in my template, I used: {% if entry.GamesGraphicsMode != "select" %}

Comment: Sure, that'll work. I'm still pretty sure there was some junk data (a blank space, invisible characters, etc) in your previous "empty" value cell though, because leaving the value empty and simply doing `{% if entry.GamesGraphicsMode %}` should work, too (I've done it like that many times). Anyway, it's that you got it working :)